# Getting error while starting ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, path, environment-variables, boot

Every time i start my system i received this message:

"Error found when loading /etc/profile:

/etc/profile: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/etc/profile: line 1:`iamgreat# /etc/profile: system-wide.profile file for
the Bourne shell(sh(1))'

As a result the session will not be configured correctly
You should fix the problem as soon as feasible."

Can Someone please help me fix this issue?